# Posibles bugs en VisualStudio trabajando con WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Esta mañana inicie mi proyecto que había dejado funcionando el pasado Viernes, cuando intento correr el proyecto para ver en que me había quedado este no me dejaba compilar porque no existía una referencia (la cual el Viernes funcionaba perfectamente). Reinicie la referencia y todo funcionaba correctamente pero ahora tengo dos problemas nuevos y la verdad no encontré de donde nace el error ya que todo esto el pasado Viernes no sucedía.

Como se observa la clase `VentanaPrincipal` no esta heredando nada de `Window`, de echo ni si quiera sabe que es `Window` Visual Studio, pero al compilar funciona todo correctamente. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago `ctrl+Enter` para acudir a las sugerencias del `Intellicense` me aparece esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no, no tengo ningún parámetro a lo largo de mi código con el nombre `key` porque no uso el ingles para nombrar funciones, variables, parámetros o lo que sea.

**Uso Visual Studio 2019.**

> Lo que intente

- Intente reiniciando el Visual Studio
- Moviendo los archivos a otra carpeta
- El reinstalar el visual studio no creo que sea la solución porque los demás proyectos funcionan correctamente

Comment: Usa XAML Designer View?

Comment: Si, tiene alguna idea de lo que pueda ser ?

Comment: Perdoneme amigo, habla Ingles? Encuentro [la misma pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810814/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-key-only-happens-on-xaml-designers-desig) en StackOverlfow

Comment: El problema es que el error no me lo trae en tiempo de ejecución, como lo especifique en la pregunta el mismo corre perfectamente, el error lo tira SOLO si hago ctrl+enter, de echo puedo seguir programando y probando mi codigo  pero sin ayuda del Intellicense básicamente por eso creo que es mas bien un bug que un problema en mi codigo

Comment: Puede leer 
[esto] 
(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/637357/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-key-1.html) . Desafortunadamente, tambien no tienen solucion. Solo recomendaron actualizar VS.

Comment: Tengo la ultima version de Visual Studio, al parecer el inconveniente se debe a varios motivos o sucesos en paralelo. Como bien dices no hay una solución en concreto al respecto

Comment: "key" no es el valor de alguna variable que tu hayas hecho, eso es una variable que está en algunos objetos como consultas LINQ, en algunos tipos de arrays / listas..

Answer (score 2):

Establece `IsDesignTimeCreatable = True` en tu `MainWindows.xaml`

pero es mejor que no utilices mucho el **designer** trabaja con el propio **xaml** cuando haces la vista en paralelo se ralentiza.

Me pasa porque uso vs 2010. no se cual vs estas utilizando.